# Django Redirecting to custom prefilled form

Tags: python, django

So I have the following issue regarding a custom project. I made a page with different pets which are ready for adoption. Each one has a button for Details. I want when a user is Logged In to see a button which indicates that saying "Adopt". When the button is pressed I want to redirect him to a new page with some prefilled fields from the Pet model (the pet which is ready for adoption) and I want the user to fill few new fields. When he press another button (Send...etc.) to tell him that the request is send out. I tried and see that the pk of the first ready for adoption animal is 1, but when I go the url it is saying that no URL is found. Here are some of my code.

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('adoption/create/', AnimalAdoptCreateView.as_view(), name='animal_adopt_create'),
    path('adoption/', AnimalAdoptListView.as_view(), name='adoption_animals'),
    path('adoption/details/<int:pk>', AnimalAdoptDetails.as_view(), name='adoption_animals_details'),
    path('adoption/details/<int:pk>/adopt/', AnimalAdoptFormSendView.as_view(), name='adopt_form'),
]


views.py

class AnimalAdoptDetails(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = AnimalAdoptReadyCreate
    template_name = 'animal_adopt_detail.html'

class AnimalAdoptFormSendView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = AnimalAdoptSend
    form_class = AnimalAdoptSendForm
    template_name = 'animal_adopt_form.html'

models.py

class AnimalAdoptReadyCreate(models.Model):
    animal_choice = {
        ('dog', 'Dog'),
        ('cat', 'Cat'),
        ('other', 'Other')
    }

    animal_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    animal_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=animal_choice)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    details = models.TextField()
    other = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pets_for_adoption/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.animal_name


class AnimalAdoptSend(AnimalAdoptReadyCreate):
    place_to_live = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    picture_of_place = models.ImageField(upload_to='owner_homes/%Y/%m/%d/')
    other_pets = models.TextField()
    other_details = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


forms.py

class AnimalAdoptSendForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AnimalAdoptSend
        fields = [
            'animal_name', 'picture', 'location', 'animal_type', 'place_to_live', 'other_pets', 'other_details', 'picture_of_place'
        ]

htmls:
This is for details of each pet:

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div>
            <h2>Pet name: {{ object.animal_name }}</h2>
            <p><img src="{{ object.picture.url }}" alt="None"></p>
            <p>Location: {{ object.location }}</p>
            <p>Type: {{ object.animal_type }}</p>
            <p>Contact with the current owner: {{ object.user.phone }}</p>
            {% if object.other %}
                <p>Other Details: {{ object.other }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <button><a href="{% url 'adopt_form' object.pk %}">Adopt</a></button>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}

and this is supposed to be the form with the prefilled fields. I was not sure should it be like a form or no, I tried both but I recieved the error that I mentioned:

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <main>
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <form method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
{#            <h2>Pet name: {{ object.animal_name }}</h2>#}
{#            <p><img src="{{ object.picture.url }}" alt="None"></p>#}
{#            <p>Location: {{ object.location }}</p>#}
{#            <p>Type: {{ object.animal_type }}</p>#}
{#            <p>Place to Live: {{ object.place_to_live }}</p>#}
{#            <p>Other Pets: {{ object.other_pets }}</p>#}
{#            {% if object.other_details %}#}
{#                <p>Other Details: {{ object.other_details }}</p>#}
{#            {% endif %}#}
{#            <p><img src="{{ object.picture_of_place.url }}" alt="None"></p>#}
        {% endif %}
    </main>
{% endblock %}


ANd this is the main urls:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('common.urls')),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("accounts.urls")),
    path('petshop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('animals/', include('animals.urls')),
]
```

Thank you,

So the error is this when I tried :

Page not found (404)
No animal adopt send found matching the query
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/animals/adoption/details/1/adopt/
Raised by:  animals.views.AnimalAdoptFormSendView

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is here:

```
path('adoption/details/<int:pk>/adopt/', AnimalAdoptFormSendView.as_view(), name='adopt_form')
```

Should be:

```
path('adoption/details/adopt/<int:pk>/', AnimalAdoptFormSendView.as_view(), name='adopt_form')
```

I don't think the generic class-based UpdateView can retrieve the parameter if it is not in the last position.